# Trying to print out contents of userspace memory

Tags: c, operating-system, virtual-memory

On a 64-bit NetBSD system, why does this code just hang after printing a few lines and not segfault or complain? Changing `*add--` to `*add++` understandably segfaults since the process tries to access kernel memory after some iterations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void main() {
        uint8_t x = 5;
        uint8_t *add = &x;
        printf("%u\n", sizeof(void*));

        while (1)
                printf("%p %x\n", add, *add--);

}
```

Comment: You cannot expect a program with undefined behavior to behave in any specific way, no matter what that way might be. After all, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: OTOH, this question is asking why it does so in a *specific* implementation (at least insofar as OS, although it's still potentially missing other details). While behavior may be undefined "in general", it does not mean that a specific case cannot be 'defined'/explained.

Comment: @user2864740 Well, you have to differ between *undefined* and *implementation defined* behavior. The latter should be defined and documented, while the first could be basically anything.

Comment: Why is this undefined behavior? My process is trying to access userspace memory, which it has every right to do.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour in terms of C, but not necessarily undefined behaviour in terms of your processor, OS, etc. In other words the C language says "you can't do this" and often compilers will not do what you expect, but in this case it's likely that the compiler *is* doing what you expect, so that's not why it hangs. Have you tried looking at the assembly code and/or stepping through it in a debugger?

Comment: You should try compiling with `-O0` or equivalent optimization level. You then *might* see some expected behavior. You never know how the compiler optimizes UB.

Comment: Why you can't check it under gdb? where exactly does it hangs.